# Is the function malloc() working in a for loop?

Tags: c

It's from a course question, I need to read 576 numbers from a file to a 1-D array, then print it as a  18*32 matrix. What confuses me it that I want to filter numbers that greater than 80 from former 1-D array and put them into struct. The struct should contain the X,Y-axis info and the number itself. Obviously I need to create a array of struct, but I don't know the length of the array.(I have to filter it first to get the length) When I use malloc() to allocate the space of this struct array in for loop, It doesn't work.

```
struct Axis{
int x_axis;
int y_axis;
}mat[576];
// the struct to save the number info that greater than 80
struct NODE{
int x_axis;
int y_axis;
int num;
};
struct NODE* nodes;
int num_cont=0;
void Find_num(int* Arr);

int main(){
FILE*   Ref_Data;
int     Data[576];
errno_t err = fopen_s(&Ref_Data,"D://exam/1.txt", "r");
if (Ref_Data == NULL) {
    printf("Ref_Data.txt failed to open.\r\n");
    printf("%d\r\n",err);
    system("pause");
}
else {
    printf("The file is now opened.\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 576; i++)
    {
        fscanf_s(Ref_Data, "%d", &Data[i]);
    }
    }
    fclose(Ref_Data);
    printf("the matrix is \r\n");
    for (int row = 0; row < 32; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 18; col++)
        {
            printf("%d%*s", Data[row*18+col],1,"");
            mat[row * 18 + col].x_axis = col+1;
            mat[row * 18 + col].y_axis = row+1;
        }
        printf("\r\n");

    }
    printf("the result of num filting : \r\n");
    Find_num(Data);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_cont; i++)
    {
        printf("node_num is %d, node_x_axis is %d, node_y_axis is %d\r\n",nodes[i].num, nodes[i].x_axis, nodes[i].y_axis);
    }
    free(nodes);
    system("pause");
}

// the function to filter num
void Find_num(int* Arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 576; i++)
    {
        if (Arr[i] > 80)
        {
            num_cont++;
            nodes = (struct NODE*)malloc(sizeof(nodes)*num_cont);
            nodes[num_cont-1].num = Arr[i];
            nodes[num_cont-1].x_axis = mat[i].x_axis;
            nodes[num_cont-1].y_axis = mat[i].y_axis;
        }
    }
}
```

the result of code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnEXI.png)
i try printing the array of struct, the numbers are wrong, but some are right.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], extracted from your code, along with the output it produces (as text, not image). As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. That said, `malloc()` does not work differently when called in a loop.

Comment: Yes it works in a loop. But every time you iterate the loop you will create new memory, loosing the old memory you created. It's likely that you want to use[ **[`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)** instead.

Comment: There's no reason to reallocate the array if you are just going to shrink it.

Comment: On another couple of notes, first please try to avoid using global variables. Pass data and variables as arguments instead. Then also try to avoid using [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). Like for example, what does `576` really mean? What about `80`? What's so special about those numbers? If you have (symbolic) named constants for those values, it's hopefully easier to understand.

Comment: With your memory allocation with ```malloc``` you kept growing the memory usage for no reason without ```free```ing them once not needed anymore. Instead use ```realloc``` to expand the size of the allocated memory chunk and do not forget to ```free``` it when you finished the stuff with the allocated chunk.

Comment: you're leaking memory with each consecutive call to `malloc`, it allocates a new, unintialized area of memory, that's what you see in output

Comment: This is wrong:  `malloc(sizeof(nodes)*num_cont)`  Remember, `nodes` is just a pointer.  You want the size of the structure, not the size of a pointer.  Use `malloc(sizeof(*nodes)*num_cont)`.  You could also use `malloc(sizeof(struct NODE)*num_cont)`.

Comment: Actually you should be using `realloc`, as others pointed out.  But the size problem is the same.

Comment: @thenyik Jin, Rather than post text as a picture, post text as _text_.  That improves the quality and usefulness of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the function malloc() working in a for loop?

Yes, it is working just fine. As pointed in comments [like this from @Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78105922/is-the-function-malloc-working-in-a-for-loop#) the way you called `malloc` is wrong. And where are the corresponding calls to `free()`?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 576; i++)
    {
        if (Arr[i] > 80)
        {
            num_cont++;
            nodes = (struct NODE*)malloc(
                sizeof(nodes) * num_cont);
            nodes[num_cont - 1].num    = Arr[i];
            nodes[num_cont - 1].x_axis = mat[i].x_axis;
            nodes[num_cont - 1].y_axis = mat[i].y_axis;
        }
    }
```

For every call in the loop the poor `nodes` pointer is overwriten and lost for good.

**You need a better model. If you just follow the course question you can make your life easier. Do not try to solve the problem in one time.**

### An example

> I need to read 576 numbers from a file to a 1-D array, then print it as a 18*32 matrix.

#### a model for the input data

So there are some numbers, and a file. The array can be seen as a sequence of numbers, or divided in some lines, e.g 576 numbers or 18 * 32 = 576 numbers. In `C` you write it this way:

```
#define SO_TOTAL 576
#define SO_ROWS 18
#define SO_COLS 32

typedef struct
{
   union
   {
       unsigned array[SO_TOTAL];
       unsigned matrix[SO_ROWS][SO_COLS];
   };
   unsigned size;
 } Data;
```

`union` provides alternative ways to look at the same area in memory, and you use the alternatives by name, as in

```
   Data thing;
   thing.array[0] = 42;
   thing.matrix[1][2] = 30;
```

So the first part of the code could be a function declared

```
    Data* get_the_array(unsigned N, const char* file);
```

And you could use it like

```
    Data* data = get_the_array(40, in_file);
    // and somewhere down
    free(data);
```

#### printing the array as a matrix

Using the same model, a function like this could do the trick:

```
    int   print_the_array(Data* data, const char* msg);
```

`msg` is an optional title to avoid those nasty dozens of `printf` calls in test code. And the `union` means that you can address the data as an array of arrays, with no change. See a possible implementation:

```
int print_the_array(Data* data, const char* msg)
{
    if (data == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg == NULL)
        printf("%u rows, %u cols\n", SO_ROWS, SO_COLS);
    else
        printf("%s%u rows, %u cols\n", msg, SO_ROWS, SO_COLS);

    for (size_t r = 0; r < SO_ROWS; r += 1)
    {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < SO_COLS; c += 1)
            printf("%4d ", data->matrix[r][c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And use it like:

```
    int result = print_the_array(data, "The first test");
```

Should work just fine.

**going on**

> What confuses me it that I want to filter numbers that greater than 80 from former 1-D array and put them into struct. The struct should contain the X,Y-axis info and the number itself. Obviously I need to create a array of struct, but I don't know the length of the array.

The problem in the code is that you have no container for these *nodes*: Consider this:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned x_axis;
    unsigned y_axis;
    int      num;
} Node;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned size;
    int      limit;
    Node*    point;
} Filtered;
```

Now you know. This is called encapsulation: wrap the thing you need and give it a name, and treat is as a whole. As you know `size` and `limit` **and** have a *container* you can allocate the array of nodes with the needed size. See the code in the example.

#### filtering the input array to build the array of nodes

A simple function declared as

```
    Filtered* get_the_nodes(Data* data, int limit);
```

should work: get the address of the original `data` read from file, a trigger value `limit` and return the address of a *container* with all the matching nodes (possibly none). Like here:

```
    Data* data = get_the_array(576, in_file);
    char  msg[80];
    sprintf(msg, "\n[%u items]  ", data->size);
    print_the_array(data, msg);
    Filtered* p_node = get_the_nodes(data, SO_LIMIT);
```

#### printing the filtered nodes

Since `Filtered` has the points, plus the `size` and the `limit` used,

```
    int       print_the_nodes(Filtered* data, const char* msg);
```

this should work just fine, as in

```
#define SO_TOTAL 576
#define SO_LIMIT 80

    Data* data = get_the_array(SO_TOTAL, in_file);
    char  msg[80];
    sprintf(msg, "\n[%u items]  ", data->size);
    print_the_array(data, msg);
    Filtered* node = get_the_nodes(data, SO_LIMIT);
    print_the_nodes(node, "\n");
    free(data);
    free(node);
```

#### running the example

Using a small 4x10 model to fit ok here

```
   3  955    5    1    3    8    9    4    5    9 
 836    8    4    5  817    9    3  905  940    2 
 973    5    5    7  817    7    6    1    3    8 
   4    0    5  872    7    6    4  829    7  847
```

And a limit of `10`

```
[40 items]  4 rows, 10 cols
   3  955    5    1    3    8    9    4    5    9
 836    8    4    5  817    9    3  905  940    2
 973    5    5    7  817    7    6    1    3    8
   4    0    5  872    7    6    4  829    7  847

limit is 10, size is 10
[   0,   1] = 955
[   1,   0] = 836
[   1,   4] = 817
[   1,   7] = 905
[   1,   8] = 940
[   2,   0] = 973
[   2,   4] = 817
[   3,   3] = 872
[   3,   7] = 829
[   3,   9] = 847
```

#### in short, the data model

This is probably what you need to write and refine first, then write and test the code iteratively

```
#define SO_TOTAL 576
#define SO_ROWS 18
#define SO_COLS 32
#define SO_LIMIT 80

typedef struct
{
    unsigned size;
    union
    {
        int array[SO_TOTAL];
        int matrix[SO_ROWS][SO_COLS];
    };
} Data;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned x_axis;
    unsigned y_axis;
    int      num;
} Node;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned size;
    int      limit;
    Node*    point;
} Filtered;

Data*     get_the_array(unsigned N, const char* file);
int       print_the_array(Data* data, const char* msg);
Filtered* get_the_nodes(Data* data, int limit);
int       print_the_nodes(Filtered* data, const char* msg);
```

#### Full code of a possible implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SO_TOTAL 40
#define SO_ROWS 4
#define SO_COLS 10
#define SO_LIMIT 10

typedef struct
{
    unsigned size;
    union
    {
        int array[SO_TOTAL];
        int matrix[SO_ROWS][SO_COLS];
    };
} Data;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned x_axis;
    unsigned y_axis;
    int      num;
} Node;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned size;
    int      limit;
    Node*    point;
} Filtered;

Data*     get_the_array(unsigned N, const char* file);
int       print_the_array(Data* data, const char* msg);
Filtered* get_the_nodes(Data* data, int limit);
int       print_the_nodes(Filtered* data, const char* msg);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (SO_TOTAL != SO_ROWS * SO_COLS) return -1;
    const char* def_file = "input.txt";
    char        in_file[250];
    if (argc < 2)
        strcpy(in_file, def_file);
    else
        strcpy(in_file, argv[1]);
    Data* data = get_the_array(40, in_file);
    char  msg[80];
    sprintf(msg, "\n[%u items]  ", data->size);
    print_the_array(data, msg);
    Filtered* p_node = get_the_nodes(data, SO_LIMIT);
    print_the_nodes(p_node, "\n");
    free(data);
    free(p_node);
    return 0;
}

Data* get_the_array(unsigned N, const char* file)
{  // get 'N' values from 'file' into
    // array
    if (N == 0) return NULL;
    if (file == NULL) return NULL;
    // open file
    FILE* in = fopen(file, "r");
    if (in == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr, "could not open '%s'. Aborting\n",
            file);
        return NULL;
    }
    // create array
    Data* p = (Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data));
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        fclose(in);
        return NULL;
    }
    p->size = 0;
    int res = fscanf(in, "%d", p->array + p->size);
    while (res == 1)
    {
        ++p->size;
        res = fscanf(in, "%d", p->array + p->size);
    }
    fclose(in);
    return p;
}

int print_the_array(Data* data, const char* msg)
{
    if (data == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg == NULL)
        printf("%u rows, %u cols\n", SO_ROWS, SO_COLS);
    else
        printf("%s%u rows, %u cols\n", msg, SO_ROWS, SO_COLS);

    for (size_t r = 0; r < SO_ROWS; r += 1)
    {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < SO_COLS; c += 1)
            printf("%4d ", data->matrix[r][c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

Filtered* get_the_nodes(Data* data, int limit)
{
    // just filter the nodes over limit
    if (data == NULL) return NULL;
    // get the size
    size_t size = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < data->size; i += 1)
        if (data->array[i] > limit) size += 1;
    Filtered* p = malloc(sizeof(Filtered));
    if (p == NULL) return NULL;
    p->limit = limit;
    p->size = 0;
    if (size == 0)
    {  // no records over limit
        p->point = NULL;
        return p;
    }
    p->point = (Node*)malloc(size * sizeof(Node));
    if (p->point == NULL)
    {
        free(p);
        return NULL;
    }
    // scan 'data' and filter the nodes
    for (unsigned r = 0; r < SO_ROWS; r += 1)
        for (unsigned c = 0; c < SO_COLS; c += 1)
            if (data->matrix[r][c] > limit)
            {
                p->point[p->size].num = data->matrix[r][c];
                p->point[p->size].x_axis = r;
                p->point[p->size].y_axis = c;
                p->size += 1;
                if (p->size == size) return p;
            }
    return p;
}

int print_the_nodes(Filtered* f, const char* msg)
{
    if (f == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg == NULL)
        printf("limit is %d, size is %u\n", f->limit, f->size);
    else
        printf(
            "%slimit is %d, size is %u\n", msg,f->limit, f->size);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < f->size; i += 1)
        printf(
            "[%4d,%4d] = %d\n",
            f->point[i].x_axis, f->point[i].y_axis, f->point[i].num);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The malloc() function allocates size bytes and **returns a pointer
> to the allocated memory.**
> <sub>from the [man page for `malloc`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html), which you can see on your system by typing the command `man 3 malloc`.</sub>

```
my_malloc_1 = malloc(1);
my_malloc_2 = malloc(1);
// my_malloc_1 != my_malloc_2
```

If you try to do a vetor of `NODE`, you want something like that :

```
nodes = malloc(sizeof(struct NODE) * num_cont);
if (nodes == NULL)
    // handle syscall error in your code please
for (size_t i = 0; i < num_cont; i++)
{
    nodes[i].x_axis = your_thing;
    nodes[i].y_axis = your_thing;
    nodes[i].num    = your_thing;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At least these issues:

**Allocate to the size of the referenced object, not to the size of the pointer.**

Cast not needed in C.

Check for allocation failures.

```
// nodes = (struct NODE*)malloc(sizeof(nodes)*num_cont);
nodes = malloc(sizeof nodes[0] * num_cont);
if (nodes == NULL && num_count > 0) {
   Handle_allocaiton_error();
}
```

**Sizing best done with `size_t`**

`size_t` is the right width for array indexing and sizing, neither too narrow nor too wide, unlike `int`.

```
// int num_cont=0;
size_t num_cont = 0;
```

Note: `size_t` is an *unsigned* type.